# ViewPager with Progressbar pagination

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-cardview, viewpagerindicator

I have tried to implement a ViewPager with a ProgressBar but I can not do the design.
I also have to disable Scroll since the views can only be seen if something has been marked in the previous fragment.
Can somebody help me?

This is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_new_word"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBarNewWord"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarNewWord"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I attached the layout and design that should go but I can't do.

[image]
[image]

The progress bar indicates the percentage of progress you have when completing a survey, there are 5 pages and I need to show how much has been completed as shown in picture one and two, first choose a country and then a state, the bar Moves depending on progress

Comment: what do you want from ProgressBar?

Comment: The progress bar indicates the percentage of progress you have when completing a survey, there are 5 pages and I need to show how much has been completed as shown in picture one and two, first choose a country and then a state, the bar Moves depending on progress